# Downloading file in windows-1251 encoding format in nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fs, iconv

I want to create and download text file in `windows-1251` format. When I'm trying to use the code below, the file is downloading successfully, but, unfortunately, in `utf-8` format. Any suggestions on what am I doing wrong?

nodeCode:

```js
//node-version: v12.13.0
var iconv = require("iconv-lite");

//create txt file 
router.post("/to-text", (req, res) => {
  const arr = req.body.arr; //an array of objects

  var file2 = iconv
    .encodeStream("win1251")
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`filepath`));

  file2.on("error", function (err) {
    return res.status(500).json(err);
  });

  arr.forEach(function (v) {
     const lastChar = v[1].slice(-1);
    if (lastChar === "я") {
      v[1] = v[1] + ".";
    }
    file2.write(v.join(",") + "\n");
  });
  file2.end();
  returnres.send(file2);
});

//dowload txt file
router.get("/download", (req, res) => {
  let file_path = `filepath`;
  res.download(file_path);
});
```

ReactCode:

```js
const getText = () => {
    let arr = [];
    const date = `PLU_${Moment().format("L").split(".").join("")}.txt`;
    productsList.map((e, idx) =>
          arr.push(
            Object.values({
              a: e.hotkey,
              b: e.name,
              c: "",
            })
          )
        );
    // first request to save as text in filepath
    Axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/myapi/to-text",
      data: {
        arr,
        date,
        type: prefixType.value,
      },
      responseType: "blob",
    })
      .then((data) => {
        return data.data;
      })
      .then((resp) => {
        closeModal();
        return Axios.get("myapi/download", {
          responseType: "blob",
          params: { date },
        })
          .then((res) => res.data)
          .then((response) => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(
              new Blob(
                [
                  response,
                ],
                {
                  type: "text/plain;charset=windows-1251",
                }
              )
            );
            const link = document.createElement("a");
            link.href = url;
            link.setAttribute("download", date);
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        ErrorAlert(err);
      });
  };
```

When in React the function fires, it first creates a `txt` file in the file path on the server-side. Then downloads it, using a second request.
 To check the file formats I'm using `Notepad++`, just by opening it in the editor and viewing the below-right corner. 
 I guess that some small detail is missing, to convert the file properly, but I can not see it( Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to my problem. I was needed to encode it only once, inside the loop, while `.writing` it into the file, like:
`file.write(iconv.encode(v.join(",") + "\n", "win1251"));`
That's it, after this little manipulation it saves the file as `windows-1251`. Obviously, downloads in the same format.